# How to overlay view on top of multiple other views in a VStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, overlay, swiftui-view, swiftui-layout

In SwiftUI I currently have a VStack of views, and I'd like to put an overlay over the bottom two views, like this:

```
VStack {
  Spacer()
  Group {
    centerView
    Spacer()
  }
  .overlay(overlayedView)
}
```

The goal of the above layout is ensure that `centerView` is vertically centered, while also ensuring that the `overlayedView` goes from the top of `centerView` all the way to the bottom of the VStack.

However, the above code *actually* results in one instance of `overlayedView` getting overlayed on top of `centerView` and *another* `overlayedView` getting overlayed on top of the bottom Spacer. But what I want is a *single* `overlayedView` spread on top of both `centerView` and the bottom Spacer.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Using Group will add view modifiers to all the subviews of the group, resulting in 2 seperate overlays. To have one common overlay, you can use VStack instead of Group.

```
VStack {
  Spacer()
  VStack {
    centerView
    Spacer()
  }
  .overlay(overlayedView)
}
```

Comment: I've tried that approach, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Your approach leads to about 1/3 of space at the top and 2/3 at the bottom. The Spacers need to be in the same VStack in order to actually center the `centerView`.